# How can I filter by "ends with" using PHPUnit's --filter option?

Tags: php, regex, phpunit

I'm trying to filter a PHPUnit test suite. When I try to filter by test name using `--filter`, the tests that *exactly match* the specified string are executed, but so are any tests that *begin with* the string.

eg. If I have two tests, testExample and testExampleTwo, the following runs both tests:

```
phpunit --filter testExample tests/Example.php
```

How can I get phpunit to stick to the exact string I gave it? I've tried `/testExample$/` but that doesn't run any tests. I'm using PHPUnit 3.7.

Comment: `\btestExample\b` does this work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fully-qualified test name varies depending on whether the test has a data provider.

When there is no data provider, the test's name is simply `Example::testExample`, which would be executed using `/testExample$/`.

```
phpunit --filter '/testExample$/' tests/Example.php

/**
 * No data provider.
 */
public function testExample() {

}
```

However, with a data provider, the test becomes `Example::testExample with data set [dataset]`, which does not match the pattern `/testExample$/`.

I had to use the following pattern to get it to work as expected, which matches either the end of the string or a space character.

```
phpunit --filter '/testExample\b/' tests/Example.php

/**
 * @dataProvider  exampleData
 */
public function testExample($data) {

}
```

Comment: it will match `testExample` with a space..consider the case where you have a single word and no extra spaces. This will not match those words

Comment: @rock321987 You're right, I've updated the solution to cover both cases.

Comment: you have to include `\b` initially also otherwise it will include cases like `abcdtestExample` which i think you have to ignore

Comment: @rock321987 Every test in the suite begins with 'test' to match the PHPUnit convention, so an extra `\b` would be unnecessary.

Comment: @Sadurnias then its ok

Answer (score 0):

To add to the info above, when the test has a data provider, the filter regex can also be used to select which test case loop(s) to run. For example `--filter='thisTest\b.*#3'` will run `thisTest` with data set number 3. The filtering does not seem to work on the data values passed, only the # number.